# Bits shifting, getting incorrect value

Tags: java

For this shifting:

```
System.out.println(0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000001>>>32);
```

I'm getting this output value:

> -2147483647

Is it correct?

Comment: Randomly) While coding function counting number of active bits in integer value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) says:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Since 32 is 100000 in binary, only the five lowest bits are taken, which means you are not shifting the left-hand operand at all.

In other words, `0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000001>>>32` is equivalent to `0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000001>>>0`.

Hence the result is `0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000001`.